# Play HLS video clips from URL in AVplayer when multiple startTime's and EndTime's are received in JSON for multiple clips for the same video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

I calculated the duration to stop the clip at the received end time. Start time works fine but it never stops at end time .

```
- (CMTime)playerItemDuration
{
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = self.currentVideoVC.player.currentItem;

    if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
        CGFloat duration = [self.currentVideoVC.currentPlay.endTime floatValue] - [self.currentVideoVC.currentPlay.startTime floatValue];
        playerItem = nil;
        return CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(duration, 1);
    }

    return(kCMTimeInvalid);
}

- (void)seekToTimeValue:(CGFloat)timeInSeconds
{
    [self.currentVideoVC.player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timeInSeconds, NSEC_PER_SEC) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];

    [self.scrubberView updateCurrentTime:timeInSeconds];
}
```